# Create a final Python package from two packages

Tags: python

I have a noob question.
I have two Github packages, let's say GP1 and GP2 in two different folders.
Now, I'd like to create a script (myScript.py) that uses both of those packages including files and doing things. This is a tree similar to mine:

```
myScriptFolder
│
├── GP1
│   └── GP1Scripts
│       └── fileToIncludeFromGP1.py
│
├── GP2
│   └── fileToIncludeFromGP2.py
│
└── myScript.py
```

I tried

```
from GP1.GP1Scripts import fileToIncludeFromGP1 as gp1
from GP2 import fileToIncludeFromGP2 as gp2
```

and then:

```
gp1.function1()
gp2.function2()
```

but I have lots of errors caused by missing files from GP1 and GP2. It can't find modules or files requested in the included files. Why?

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by `lots of dependencies from GP1 and GP2 missing`? are you also trying to import a `.py` file from the `modules` within it? and those imports are inside the `GPs` folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "Github packages"?

Comment: @StackOffended Let's say that inside fileToIncludeFromGP1.py. there is an open('foo.txt', 'w'). It can't find that foo.txt file. If I run directly from fileToIncludeFromGP1.py, instead, it works.

Comment: @tripleee Two GitHub repositories, separately working

Comment: But do you mean they contain Python modules, or Python packages, or random snippets of Python code with no modularization or packaging, or something else?

Comment: Ohhh okay I think I'm getting your point... soo for example you have a function on your `fileToIncludeFromGP1.py` let's say it's `foo` now that function opens up a `.txt` file in the same directory as `fileToIncludeFromGP1.py` now when you import the `fileToIncludeFromGP1.py` module and use the function `foo`, you mean the `foo` function would give an error cause it can't find the `.txt` file? but if you run directly to `fileToIncludeFromGP1.py` it works fine? is that it?

Comment: Have you installed the packages?

Comment: @StackOffended Correct

Comment: @tripleee They are Alphapose and GASTNet from GitHub

Comment: @MadPhysicist Of course

Comment: Then why are the packages in your script folder to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have here a sample demonstration, based on my understanding here it goes.

I have this directory.

```
test
│
├── package
│   └── p1.py
|   └── test.txt
│       
│
|
│
└── m1.py
```

**p1.py**

Now when I run this code. It works fine cause you are running the `p1.py` itself and the `test.txt` is indeed on the same directory.

```
def read_text():
    with open("test.txt") as file:
        print(file.read())



read_text()
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

---

**m1.py**

Now when I run `m1.py` and imported the `p1.py` and used its `read_text` function. I get this error

```
from package import p1

p1.read_text()
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\test\m1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package import p1
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\test\package\p1.py", line 7, in <module>
    read_text()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\test\package\p1.py", line 2, in read_text
    with open("test.txt") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

### Why is this happening?

Based on my understanding as I had this issues too... This is because when you imported the module think of it like the `p1.py` is in the SAME directory as `m1.py` cause you have imported it. Now for this to work you'll have to specify the correct path now for the `test.txt` file as if the `p1.py` file is in the same directory as the `m1.py` file. Think of the `p1.py` file as in the same directory as `m1.py` now try to change the path of the `test.txt` file from the `p1.py` file to "package/test.txt" & run `m1.py`

```
def read_text():
    with open("package/test.txt") as file:
        print(file.read())
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Now as you can see it works.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got it. So there is no way to call a function from another file and let Python think it was called directly from the function file? I have many nested imports and I can't manage to resolve all the problems. I have errors like: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Hmm... tbh I am not so sure... and tbh again I also had that kind of issues when I was having my Thesis... and the only way I just do it was to change some of the `paths` as if like when the function as imported then the `path` would be relevant base where it was imported.

Comment: I'd love to hear anyone about it & probably might see that it is even possible!

Comment: I didn't get the path thing.

Comment: I mean is I had to just change for example when I'm trying to read a file... I just changed the "path" of the file to be read as if based on the directory where the module (which contains the function) is imported. Just like what I did after `"Why is thing happening?"`

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you. Let's see if someone else answers and knows if it is possible and how to do it.

Comment: Yep! I'd love to know how to :)